# Java If Statements/Spinner

Tags: java, android, if-statement, button, spinner

I'm working on an Activity where I need to start a new Activity at the click of a button based on the selected item in a spinner. I can't quite figure it out. This is what I have after clearing failed attempts.

```
spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.user_type, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);


adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if(spinner.equals("My String Here")){

                    startActivity(new Intent(Register.this, *****.class));
                }else{
                startActivity(new Intent(Register.this, *****.class));


            }}
```

Am I better off just installing two buttons with their own proper syntax starting new activities separately?

Answer (score 1):

If spinner.equals does not make any sense at all.

You should use position integer value to check your array data and then make a decision based on that value

Comment: Okay thanks, will take that into consideration. I used that method above because I was told to always use .equals from another forum. Hope this helps.

Comment: that would make sense if spinner was a of String type. You only use .equals when comparing string types.

Answer (score 1):

First things first.

```
spinner.equals("My String Here")
```

`spinner` is of type Spinner whereas `"My String Here"` is a String. You are always sure that they will never be equated the same.

Next, try to make use of your `position` and `adapter` to be able to properly construct your condition.

Comment: Okay tyvm, I can use as much feedback as possible. I'm self taught for the most part.